# Can I import SQL with PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner with PHP. I am planning to set up an application where visitors can login and play/mess around with my application.

So I want to refresh my php application once a day with a cron job. But I never wrote a cron job script before. I understand that I have to truncate all the tables/data and add the initial data.

With phpMyAdmin, I can import data. Is there any way I can import SQL file after truncate the tables?

What is the best way? Do I have to create table and insert all data?

Comment: And what format are the files you wish to import

Comment: Just to be sure: cron jobs and truncating tables in your database aren't related "things". You can however combine them if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute an sql file on your database, you don't even need phpmyadmin. if mysql and php are running on the same machine you have mysql tools installed. if you control the data dumping you can use the mysqldump/mysqlimport combo. if not you can generate an sql file and execute it with the "mysql" CLI program.

```
shell> mysql db_name < script.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not have access to the `mysql` command or you can only execute php/cgi scripts with `cron` (like on most shared hostings).

In that case, you can parse the `.sql` file in PHP and execute the queries with `mysql_query()`. There is an example at the bottom of [this page](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d158945/php/php-sgbd/sql-executer-script-sql-php/).

Answer (score 0):

[How to Backup and Restore](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/21/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/)

[Mysql Import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

[Intro to Cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)